# Generating entity classes and database schema from a Hibernate XML config file

Tags: java, php, hibernate, jakarta-ee, symfony1

Is there a tool for generating entity classes and database schemas from a Hibernate XML config file?
In PHP [Symfony framework (based on Doctrine)](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_2/Doctrine/en/03) for creating schema and model classes I've been using:

```
$ php symfony doctrine:build-model
$ php symfony doctrine:build-sql
```

How can I achieve this in Hibernate?
I found only [Reverse Engineering tool](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html) for generating config file and entity classes based on schema, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use Maven to build the DDL using hibernate, but from my experience last night you still need to have generated your entity classes previously in Java.  The Maven plugin you'd need is the Codehaus hibernate3 maven artifact, detailed here:
http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-hibernate3/hibernate3-maven-plugin/

It's not a plug and play solution, given my experiences last night :P